# platform is not defined in polymer files downloaded from website

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm trying to make a web application but i keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Platform is not defined
```

In the polymer.js file I downloaded from the website. How do H fix this?

I tried to re-download it and redid the import, which got rid of the other errors but this one persists.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also load platform.js (the polyfills). Make sure it is the first script loaded on your page and comes before any HTML imports:

```
<script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
```

The basic setup is here: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/usingelements.html#using
More info here: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/getting-the-code.html

Answer (score 0):

**platform.js** was replaced now for **webcomponents.js**

If you are sure that is all right with your  section and even so the error remains, there is something wrong with your environment (maybe some incompatibility between different versions of components or scritps).

Clear and download all your components and scripts again from the sources. I recommend use of Bower for that. Just wipe your repository and make a fresh bower install.